# Integrating a network graph with dc.js/crossfilter.js

Tags: javascript, graph, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm looking for tips and guidance on integrating a network chart with [dc.js](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/)/[crossfilter.js](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/)`.

Let's say I have some data like this:

```
[
    {
        'name': 'john',
        'sexe': 'male',
        'relative': [
            'susy',
            'mark'
        ]
    },
    {
        'name': 'susy',
        'sexe': 'female',
        'relative': [
            'susy',
            'mark'
        ]
    }
    ...
]
```

Using plain `dc.js` I can quite easily display coordinated piecharts showing proportions of males/females, percentages of people with the same name etc..

What I would like is to combine the features of `dc.js` with a network graph, so I can show who's related to who.

The idea is that ie: when selecting "females" in a piechart, the network graph would redraw itself to show exclusively the female relationships.

I'm aware the question may be vague and only loosely fit the guidelines, but I've spent hours digging across to internet for an example of combining `dc.js` charts with a network diagram.

Can integrating a network graph with `dc.js` be relatively easily achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [dc.graph.js](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.graph.js)

It follows the same sort of data model as dc.js, using crossfilter and accessor functions. The main difference is that there are two crossfilter instances, one for the nodes and one for the edges. Also, it uses accessors on the edges to retrieve the keys of the source and target boxes.

dc.graph.js is still experimental but it definitely supports the use case you describe. Please try it out and report any issues or feature requests!

Comment: Thanks! From the Maker himself :) I've been looking at dc.graph.js (I'm the guy who pointed out that Firefox issue on github)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I think it is pretty solid but there is always more to do. All contributions welcome.

Comment: @Juicy Did you happen to make this integration work?

Comment: @anmolkoul never got further on this project

Comment: @Gordon Is there any implementation of this coupling that you may have seen?

Comment: I use it in some projects - unfortunately I don't have any sample data, but there is a vizgems example in the project you could look at. The way I use it allows dc.js charts to filter the graph but not the other way around - is this what you want? (I haven't experimented with a graph showing aggregated data either.) If you have example data you can put in a fiddle, please open another question and I'll help you connect it.